# How to filter data by start date to end date django then display the data in the template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

#### models.py

```
class Income(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    capital = models.IntegerField(null=True, verbose_name='Money Capital')
    revenue = models.IntegerField(null=True, verbose_name='Total Revenue')
    profit = models.IntegerField(null=True, verbose_name='Total Profit')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.profit
```

#### forms.py

```
from django import forms
from . models import Income


class DateChoiceField(forms.Form):
    date1 = forms.ModelChoiceField (
        queryset=Income.objects.values_list("date", flat=True).distinct(),
    )
    date2 = forms.ModelChoiceField (
        queryset=Income.objects.values_list("date", flat=True).distinct(),
    )
```

#### views.py

```
if request.method == "POST":
        form = DateChoiceField(request.POST)
        date1 = request.POST.get('date1')
        date2 = request.POST.get('date2')
        if 'form1' in request.POST:
            if form.is_valid():
                selectedDate1 = form.cleaned_data["date1"]
                selectedDate2 = form.cleaned_data["date2"]
                start = datetime(selectedDate1)
                end = datetime(selectedDate2)
                filterYearMonth = Income.objects.filter(date__gte=start).filter(date__lte=end)

            else:
                filterYearMonth = Income.objects.all()

    else:
        form = DateChoiceField()
        filterYearMonth = Income.objects.all()

context = {
    'filterYearMonth': filterYearMonth,
        'form': form,
}
return render (request, "dashboard/dashboard.html", context)
```

#### dashboard.html

```
<form method="POST" action="/dashboard/">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form }}
            <button type="submit" name="form1">Submit</button>
        </form>

        <h4>Filter</h4>
        <table>

            {% for item in filterYearMonth %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ item.date }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.capital }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.revenue }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.profit }}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}

        </table>
```

I'm close to solving it but it keeps displaying all the data and i got this "Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices." whenever i try submitting the start and end date.[This is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvJyq.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
class DateChoiceForm(forms.Form):
    date1 = forms.ModelChoiceField (
        queryset=Income.objects.values_list("date", flat=True).distinct(),
    )
    date2 = forms.ModelChoiceField (
        queryset=Income.objects.values_list("date", flat=True).distinct(),
    )
```

A ModelChoiceField expects you to select a Model instance, but instead your queryset is giving it raw dates to select. So your form is getting confused when you submit those dates back when it really wanted to get Incomes. A ModelChoiceField queryset should return a queryset of model instances, not just values.

But I understand why you did it that way. It looks like your form user doesn't care about the backend implementation of "Incomes", they only care about choosing dates.

There is a way to separate out the view logic from the backend logic. You can do this by adding a [`label_from_instance`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField) that displays the date to the user, but passes through the Income associated with it to the backend Form. You can accomplish that by making a custom Field class.

Something like:

```
class IncomeField(ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj.date


class DateChoiceField(forms.Form):
    income_1 = IncomeField(
        queryset=Income.objects.all().distinct(),
    )
    income_2 = IncomeField (
        queryset=Income.objects.all().distinct(),
    )
```

And then adjust your [FormView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/) accordingly.